# Unable to create .net maui AppShell ShellItem and TabBar using C# markup

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I have an app in .NET MAUI with XAML for the UI.  I converted all the XAML to C# markup except for the AppShell.  A sample of what I want to convert is below:

```
<ShellItem Route="LoginPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate authentication:LoginPage}"/>
    </ShellItem>

    <TabBar >
        <Tab
            Title="{Binding TitleFeed}"
            >
            <ShellContent
                Title="{Binding TitleFeed}"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate feed:FeedPage}"
                Route="FeedPage" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
            Title="{Binding TitleSettings}"
            >
            <ShellContent
                Title="{Binding TitleSettings}"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate settings:SettingsPage}"
                Route="SettingsPage" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

I am expecting to define the ShellItem (default page) and the TabBar in C# markup and remove the use of XAML.

In particular, I am struggling to define this in C# markup for the ContentTemplate binding to one of the Content Pages. e.g. The ContentTemplate definition below does not work:

```
ShellContent shellContentFeedPage = new()
        {
            Title = AppShellViewModel.TitleFeed,
            ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)FeedPage,
            Route = "FeedPage"
        };
```

I can't find any examples of how to do this online...  Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project to achieve your request. Use the `Items.Add(ShellItem)` in the AppShell can do that.

In the code behind:

```
public AppShell()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     Items.Add(new ShellContent()
     {
         Title = "MainPage",
         ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MainPage()),
         Route = "MainPage"
     });
     var tab = new Tab()
     {
         Items = {
             new ShellContent()
             {
                 Title = "Page1",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new NewPage1()),
                 Route = "Page1"
             },
             new ShellContent()
             {
                 Title = "Page2",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new NewPage2()),
                 Route = "Page2"
             }
         },
     };
     var tabbar = new FlyoutItem() { Title = "Tabbar" , Route = "Tab"};
     tabbar.Items.Add(tab);
     Items.Add(tabbar);
 }
```

And the result image:

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Regiter the AppShell DI and the LoginPage:

```
Services.AddTransient(typeof(AppShell)).AddTransient(typeof(LoginPage));
```

And then in the App.cs:

```
public App(AppShell appShell)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = appShell;
}
```

And in the AppShell.cs:

```
public AppShell(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Items.Add(new ShellContent()
    {
        Title = "LoginPage",
        ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => serviceProvider.GetService<LoginPage>()),
        Route = "LoginPage"
    });
```

Comment: Did the `ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new LoginPage(LoginViewModel viewmodel))` not work? @James

Comment: Hi, that is amazing thankyou.  I have hit the next hurdle which is that my LoginPage has a constructor that expects a ViewModel to be passed.

public class LoginPage : BaseContentPage<LoginViewModel>

The ViewModel itself has a constructor with DI:

    public LoginViewModel(
        IConnectivity connectivity,
        IDialogService dialogService,
        IStringLocalizer<ProjectStrings> localizer
        ) : base(connectivity, dialogService, localizer)
    {

I have registered all these DIs.
In XAML I didn't need to pass anything to the page...

Comment: Did the ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new LoginPage(LoginViewModel viewmodel))

I tried this but no.

Comment: Please check the update part in my answer. @James

Comment: Awesome thankyou!  My project is now XAML free :)